# Solution for display image in library website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, thumbnails

In my website, I have a library contain all image of user, I want to display all image in this library. How can I do it?

[image]

I have solution but I can’t do it. This’s my solution. I’ll create thumbnail for each image and display it in library. Size of thumbnail is very small, so I don’t worry about performance. If I create thumbnail in my server. It must download, read and resize these images, then it return for my website. This way I feel not good. I have many images, each customer have about hundreds images, size of each image about 1mb or 2mb. I think have no server can handle it. Another way is create thumbnail on client by jQuery, but I can’t do it and my friend talk with me. jQuery don’t handle it. How can I do it for my solution? Hope you understand what I mean

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use pagination if you would like to return million images in a page
so for instance 50 images per page to keep up with your web performance

Comment: My boss require have no page, It like library on window apllication

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate thumbnails on server and show thumbnails in the gallery. When a user clicks on a thumbnail in the gallery, show the full image.

Comment: If I create thumbnail on server, do you think server will overload ? because It must handle many thing

Comment: No, if you manage things properly. Alternatively you can set another server for generating thumbnails if the number is really big. Or do image processing in batch to handle server load issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think your first idea is better. Because you don't want to show the images in actual size and you want to make them smaller. So using their thumbnail is a good solution. If you think this could add some complexity you can make the thumbnails for each image when user uploads them and in your view just use the thumbnails.